# Hiding, showing, and applying functions to only visible lines with ability to restore in VIM?

Tags: vim, text-files

I have an editor I am attempting to emulate that has some very nice features.  One feature of the editor is to hide lines of a file (similar to a fold but without decorations) and apply commands operations only to those lines which remain visible.  The hidden lines can then be brough back.
For example the user sees

```
    Smurf
    Apple
    Bubble
    Tree
    Dog
```

The user says show-non-matching-lines (SNML) *e*

```
    Smurf
    Dog
```

The user runs a command paste-after-line (PAL) followed by a token, $ say, and gets

```
    Smurf$
    Dog$
```

The user says show-all-lines (SAL)

```
    Smurf$
    Apple
    Bubble
    Tree
    Dog$
```

I know this is doable in VIM but I am at a loss at how to store per line properties without resorting to modifying the lines in some way.  Please nudge me in the right direction or way of thinking...

**Update**:
Using

```
:set foldtext=MyFoldingFunction
```

I can manipulate how text is folded with help from the following variables

```
v:foldstart Line num of 1st folded line 
v:foldend Line num of last folded line
```

I guess I would have to enumerate all the folds while applying functions as I am applying text formatting and figure out if a line is folded away.  I really want a method to store per line properties in vim... I guess I am out in the dark corners here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`folddoopen` does what you want; it executes some command on every line that isn't part of a closed fold.  To append a `$` to every line that isn't currently folded, you can do

```
:foldd norm A$
```

See `:h folddoopen` and `:h folddocclosed`.  It doesn't completely "hide" the folded text, you can still see the fold markers, but it's pretty close.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know of :he :g (global). If you can account for the lines by way of regex, (which may not be in your case but often is) and apply an ex command upon it. eg.

:g/\(Smurf\|Dog\)/norm A$

finds a line with Smurf or Dog, then uses :he normal to apply normal mode append $ at the end of line.

This may not be as 'visual' as your editor, but may be potentially a lot more powerful